# Slow Magento - Mage_Core_Model_Session

Tags: cache, session, profiler

For some reason this past week my magento store has started loading slowly, particularly the time to first byte being the issue.

I've disabled an extension that I installed but to no avail. I've ran the profiler and the slowest loading item is

CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Core_Model_Session

Has anyone seen this before? I'm having trouble finding anything online.

The site is memcached and session data is stored using the DB.

Before this last week the site was loading quickly, so not 100% sure what has caused such a change.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm not sure if I can single out the session object in the profiler?

The website in question is [www.normadorothy.com](http://www.normadorothy.com)

Thanks

Comment: First of all don't store sessions in database like MySQL. There are countless session writes on a page render. And there are more in checkout pages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try move session storage from MySQL to Memcached or even better to Redis, since you already use Memcached for cache storage - check [Cm_RedisSession](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_RedisSession) for extension and local.xml config sample with Redis as session storage.